# Hard reload iframe on partent page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a master page which has 2 iframes - which are frequently updated. The problem is when I reload the master page - both of the iframes LOAD from CACHE (Chrome takes the cached versions no matter how much time has passed after the last updates of the iframe content). This is so frustrating. Can I force the master page to load the iframes FROM SERVER each time it is reloaded?

Thank you!

Dave

Comment: all the methods offered in this link DO NOT WORK!

Comment: @daverichards that is great. However, we expect you to do your research before posting. So ideally this question would contain data as to why this link doesn't help you. You probably tried a couple of these methods, to say they didn't work, right? So please post results of these tries. Let us know what doesn't work, and what you expected from them instead. If you just say "they don't work", this question will likely be closed as a duplicate. You may be right, but the burden of proof is on the user asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the page then you add time like this www.example.com/iframe.html?q=201710191034123

Code

```
var d = new Date();
var iframe = $('#secondPage');
iframe.attr('src','www.yoursite.com/yourpage?g='+d.getTime())
```

Comment: thank you - maybe you can show me the full code - how is this done? I have this code for iframe:  <iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html" height="650" width="1837" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>

Comment: Hi @daverichards I have added the code

Comment: thank you! can yo please put this in FIDDLE?  this code needs to be different for each iframe?

Comment: Hi you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/xz58rut5/

Comment: thank you - I get this error when using your code:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: also -  Ferhat - is there a way to just add some random value to the SRC itself inside the iframe tag????

Comment: It is already unique number, also it works on jsfiddle can you share your code in here?

Comment: <script>
    var d = new Date();
 var iframe = document.getElementById('secondPage');
 iframe.setAttribute('src','https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html?g='+d.getTime());
     </script>                                 <iframe id="secondPage"  height="650" width="1837" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>

Comment: If I have multiple iframes - will I need separate codes for each of these?

Comment: Please try this <iframe id="secondPage" height="650" width="1837" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe><script> var d = new Date(); var iframe = document.getElementById('secondPage'); iframe.setAttribute('src','ubs.com/global/en.html?g='+d.get‌​Time()); </script>

Comment: SUPERB - IT WORKS - so the javascript code needs to be placed after the iframe? what if I have 3 iframes - can I just make multiple scrips with their IDs?

Comment: Just set d variable that looks like this d=new Date() .. iframe code.. and again d=new Date() ...

Comment: will this work in all broswers??

Comment: you mean I need to creatE new variable like d - maybe g ?

Comment: Yes because when you use it getting new time

Comment: will this work in all browsers?? DO YOU THINK IT IS FUTURE-PROOF? is there any probability an update of browsers can make this not to work?

Comment: I think it will bork because we use primitive code but i am not sure safari. If you use jquery it wull work whole browser. But please change code document.geelementById  instead of $('#secondPage') and iframe.setattribute instead of iframe.attr('src', same code)

Comment: can you please be so kind as to please send me the final variant here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1jrrn481/ here is working code

Comment: FANTASTIC - THIS IS THE MULTI IFRAME VERSION - should the script be placed above the iframes?

Comment: Yes should be or use in document ready

Comment: short question - what this stands for: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: It is for  jsfiddle if you already inlude jquery library then you don't need it

Comment: dear Ferhat - can you please take a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/hpyv3je1/  it does not seem to work on this page but works wonderfully on the other pages...

Comment: I am not sure but there is one extra quetos  please delete it that I have got into brackets  below code before height  `<div id="rectangle3" class=""><iframe src="https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html"(")height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></div>`

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply....I corrected the code and it still does not work - please look here - http://jsfiddle.net/hpyv3je1/1/   it gives this error - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at 162

Comment: which refers to this line iframe = $('#firstPage');

Comment: You should add JQuery library `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: WONDERFUL!!! THANK YOU FOR YOUR FABULOUS HELP!!! TESHEKKUR EDERIM!!))) MUKKEMEL!)

Comment: ONE MORE QUESTION IT SAYS Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt‌​4='). The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> delete it

Comment: I put it as this yes?     
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>; One final question I am using the dreamweaver CC 2017 - the iframes keep flashing black and white  - what do you think might be the reason for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jbae3vyL/

Comment: I could n't understand what you are saying, your document backgroud is black, and I think iframe backgroud (called by iframe) is white hence you thought is flashing

Comment: yes - it is all working great now - thank you for your time!!!) wish I could add you as friend here) have a great day!)

Comment: You are welcome of it is possible then you can add as friend

Comment: Hello  Ferhat - how are you????)) I have one more question - I have an image which loads inside an IFRAME which is refreshed each time with your code - but the image gets taken from the cache!! can you please help me with this as well? how can I force an image to reload from server each time?

Comment: Hi Dave, I am good and hope you are very well, I can give you some advice but I need to see your code for exact solution, so you can use same algorithm if image name is same but content is different, then it will try to load from server. If it wont be solution then you can access on skype here is my skype account ferhatbas1981@hotmail.com

Comment: thank you!"))))) I am using this code to refresh an image:                             
       d = new Date();
$("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());        I am using this line to show the image -            <img src="myimg" class="resize">             it does not work((((

Comment: How can I reach full code or test environment for what you want to do?

Comment: thank you) here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/edbf1rtq/   I cannot load the image via the second placeholder - myimg

Comment: Hi You can see working code in https://jsfiddle.net/napa6h4a/

Comment: thank you for your fabulous reply - this code will autorefresh an image each 3 seconds? Can you please help me make the image be fresh-loaded just each time the page is reloaded?.....I just need the image to be downloaded from server each time the page is reloaded

Comment: d = new Date();
 $("#myimg").attr("src", "http://i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jp?d="+d.getTime());  just use these two rows code

Comment: also your img doesnt have id defintion  dont forget add in your code id="myimg"

Comment: thanks)))) please help me make a working fiddle!) I use this and it does not work....<script>
 
d = new Date(); 
$("#myimg").attr("src", "i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jp?d="+d.getTime())
</script>

Comment: Hi https://jsfiddle.net/yoLopt3s/ this code without timer

Comment: thank you!) not sure what I am doing wrong - can you please check this one last time Ferhat? https://jsfiddle.net/bcozxp5t/

Comment: You miss one letter in js that is ....jp?d= it should be ...jpg?d=

Comment: thank you but it still does not work(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: do you think you can correct this fiddle one last time? https://jsfiddle.net/bcozxp5t/

Comment: because your js fiddle doesnt have jquery library please add this as extarnal library https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Also you have to use document.ready or your script have to after html code.

Comment: I think stackoverflow admin will banned to us because here is not chat platform. please send to me mail

Comment: great - sent the email - pls check!)

Comment: ferhatbas1981@hotmail.com

Comment: yes - sent the email to you)

Comment: the error I get = myimg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: I didnt get your email

Comment: pls check - Line7

Comment: which code this jsfiddle.net/bcozxp5t where is code

Comment: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/bcozxp5t/1/ please make it work!)

Comment: Hi you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/r351s50y/1/